# Using req.user outside of a router.post or router.get

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Is there a way for me to be able to use `req.user` outside of a post or get request? I am asking this because I want to use this variable somewhere else. The `req.user` is from the user schema which is defined like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  health: {
    type: Number,
  },
 energy: {
   type: Number,
 },

  attack: {
    type: Number,
  },
  defence: {
    type: Number,
  },
  endurance: {
  type: Number
  },
  exp: {
  type: Number
  },
  power: {
    type: Number
  },
  charactername: {
    type: String
  },
  characterimg: {
    type: String
  },
  alive: {
  type: String
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Now is there a way for me to acces `req.user` outside a get or post request? Or can I access that schema in another way which does not include the `req.user?

To give you a small example:

```
 router.post('/mission1btn',  ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
   const user = req.user
```

Above is where I use it, but now I would like to use it outside of that. In for example this place:

```
function check() {
if (user.endurance = 100) {
//do something
}
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by *"outside a ... request"*. Do you mean outside the request handler, or outside the request-response cycle entirely? Can you *pass* the user details?

Comment: I added an example at the bottom.

Comment: That hasn't clarified anything. You're showing where you *can* access it, not where you *can't*. And please note that Stack Snippets are for code that can run in the browser, which Express doesn't.

Comment: I cant acces it outside of the router.post or router.get. So no where else exept for inside what i am showing you. So this means the entire  js file with the exeption of that i showed you. If that is not clear then i dont know what is. The schema is in a different file called User.js by the way.

Comment: But when does the code outside the route handler (the function you pass to the `get` and `post` methods) actually get called? Because if it's from the route handler, then just *pass the user object*.

Comment: Please [edit] to put a [mre] *in the question*, not off-site.

Comment: Done, i dont know how else i can explain this you.

Comment: If people stop deleting my code i could actually show it you.

Comment: I edited again, have a quick look before someone removes it again.

Comment: I reverted it, and will do so again. What's the point of showing more code that's *inside the route handler* where (as your example shows) you can *already access `req.user`*? My request was that you explain where you're trying to access it but currently *can't*. And please note the *minimal* when you do so.

Comment: I am just trying to acces it in a normal function that is outside of the get or post request, but is in the same file basically.

Comment: *What* normal function, and *how does it get called*? Why doesn't `check` just take `user` as a *parameter*?

Comment: I want it to get called when the page is loading in, so i guess i will just use check() to trigger it?

Comment: I don't know quite what you mean by *"when the page is loading in"*, but why not `check(req.user)`? That's how you get data from one scope to another, you **pass it**.

Comment: Yeah that passing seems to work, thanks for help. But next time no need to be hostile, i just didn't know how to explain it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider your Mongoose user definition is in file `models/User.js`.

in any other code you can find one of users from database and perform actions with it using this code

```
"use strict";

const User = require('./models/User.js');


User.findOne({name:"test"}, function(error,user) {
   if(error) {
     throw error;
   }
    // user here is the same object as `req.user` 
    console.log(user.name); // outputs "test"
    if (user.endurance = 100) {
      //do something
    }
  });
```